# BASH command to pinpoint location in a .txt file

Tags: bash

I am looking for a way to pinpoint an exact location in a .txt file.

ie. I have a text that is say, 80,000 words in length, and I want to locate the point in the text that is 50,000 words in.

Any suggestions on how I might do this in BASH?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define a word?

Comment: How do you define location in a file. Line and column? Consecutive character?

Comment: find location and do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how do you define location here and more importantly what you want to do after finding location

You can use following command on bash to print *N* th word in a file

```
awk '{print $N}' RS= file
```

Comment: This is perfect - just one quick follow on query - can you set N so that's a range? Say %50000-50010, giving me a sequence of 10 words rather than just one word?

Comment: @R14 You can use loop for such requirement. `awk '{for(i=N;i<M;i++) print $i}' RS= file`, where in example `N=50000 and M=50010`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops, nested. The outer loop reads the file line by line; the inner loop iterates over the words in a line (using `for word in $line`). Once you have found the position, `echo` the line and column numbers, then `exit`.

The only tricky bit is calculating the column number you are on, so I'd recommend printing out the word-number-within-that-line instead of the column number - that's easier to keep track of in bash I think.